# Mounting hard drives problem

Tags: mount, hard-drive, format, chmod

Why doesn't Ubuntu mount hard drives automatically when it's launching? Moreover, I cannot `chmod +x` to the files in the hard drives after mounting. They are formatted as NTFS. If NTFS is not compatible with the `chmod` command, which filesystem format is supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want filesystem mounted automatically you will have to add it to your /etc/fstab configuration.

As for chmod, permissions and some settings for ntfs filesystem - man mount will probably shed some light onto that and mounting filesystems in general.